# OleDBException with ExecuteScalar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an application with an authorisation system implemented. It has an access 2013 database with the users who can login. The database has three columns: Username, Password and Position. The position will be something like employee or manager. 

 
After logging in successfully users are shown the main form(form1.vb) but I have a few things that happen. Firstly a label is updated containing their username. And I am trying to implement a way for a 'Position' Label to also be updated depending on who is logged in. 

 
Please bear in mind I am new to vb.net.To achieve this I am using ExecuteScalar with the following code:

```
            Using conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Folders\Developing\inventoryManagement\inventoryManager.accdb")
        Using command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Position FROM im_users", conn)
            conn.Open()



            Dim position As String = CStr(command.ExecuteScalar())

            Label6.Text = position

        End Using
    End Using
```

However when I launch the application and login in it breaks with the following exception: 
 
<  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled

> ErrorCode=-2147467259
>    HResult=-2147467259
>    Message=IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).
>    Source=System.Data
>    StackTrace:
>         at >System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
>         at >System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS >dbParams, Object& executeResult)
>         at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& >executeResult)
>         at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior >behavior, Object& executeResult)
>         at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior >behavior, String method)
>         at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar()
>         at Home.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Folders\Developing\inventoryManagement\Home\Home\Form1.vb:>line 10
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& >m)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>        at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, >Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    InnerException:

Could you please advise me on how to rectify the issue?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the exception details in a quote

Comment: The InnerException text?

Comment: That is the full exception from when I press 'Copy exception to the clipboard'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the word POSITION that is an [Access Database Engine Reserved Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-E33EB3A9-8BAA-4335-9F57-DA237C63EABE)

The usual workaroud fixes the problem

```
Using command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT [Position] FROM im_users", conn)
```

The strange thing here is the error message. Usually, the usage of a reserved word ends with a `Syntax Error` message, but in this case (tested) the exact error is the one posted above.

Said that I should warn you. As is, your query returns the whole table and not just the record belonging to a specific user because you don't have a WHERE clause that identifies the correct record.
Moreover, ExecuteScalar returns the value from first column of the first row extracted by your query. Your code retrieves always the POSITION from the first record whatever it to be.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had seen this posted somewhere but I didn't realise that 'Position' was a reserved word within Access. Also thank you for the link. I will ensure to check that in future :)

Comment: Ah yes, I noticed I was missing the WHERE clause. I have now added that in so it returns the position of the user that is logged in(tested).